# what does d3Force's (d3-force-3d's) forceLink.links() do?

Tags: d3.js

I expected the #[links](https://github.com/vasturiano/d3-force-3d#link_links) function of forceLink to 'initialize' the force for a subset of links; however this function apparently does not pass a subset of links to the subsequent #distance function (in code below), which instead receives ALL the links.

Question: how does one use the #links function [or any library function] to furnish a subset of links, to which one may next apply a function such as that of #distance?

And for related clarity, perhaps it would help to see an explanation of what the links function *does* do beyond merely reapplying a force after removal/addition of graph nodes (using the [graphData](https://github.com/vasturiano/3d-force-graph) function perhaps)?

```
<html>
<head>
  <style> body { margin: 0; } </style>

  <!-- <script src="https://unpkg.com/three"></script> -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-force-3d"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/3d-force-graph"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="3d-graph"></div>
  <script>

    const graphData = {
      nodes: [
        {id:"Alice"},
        {id:"Bob"},
        {id:"George"}
      ],
      links: [
        {source: "Alice", target:"George", sourceLevel: 6},
        {source: "George", target:"Bob", sourceLevel: 7}
      ]
    };

    const elem = document.getElementById('3d-graph');
    const Graph = ForceGraph3D()(elem)
      .graphData(graphData);

    const graphLinksSubset = graphData.links
      .filter( link => link.sourceLevel === 6 );
    const graphNodesSubset = graphLinksSubset
      .map( link => {
        return [
          graphData.nodes
            .find( node => node.id === link.source ),
          graphData.nodes
            .find( node => node.id === link.target )
        ] }).flat();
    const graphDataSubset = {
      nodes: [...graphNodesSubset],
      links: [...graphLinksSubset]
    }

    Graph.d3Force('link')
      .links(graphDataSubset)
      .distance( link=> {
        return 200;
      //   return link.sourceLevel === 6 ?
      //     50 : 200
      } )
      .id( node => node.id )
      // .strength( d => linkStrength(d) )


// SAME RESULT HERE--
    // Graph.d3Force('link', d3.forceLink(graphDataSubset)
    //   .links(graphDataSubset)
    //   .distance( link=> {
    //     return 200;
    //     // return link.sourceLevel === 5 ?
    //     //   50 : 200
    //   } )
    //   .id( node => node.id )
    //   // .strength( d => linkStrength(d) )
    // );


  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your summary and question seem to be different. Do you seek an explanation of the function or a solution to a problem?

Comment: primarily a solution to the problem; but great if you/one might help to expound on the utility of the #links function.